# Wordpress Custom Permalinks rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a page called blog .
I would like all of the posts on the site to come after this page like:

```
www.site.com/blog/
www.site.com/blog/blog-post
```

I can edit the **permalinks** .
 but when I try to save them with this custom structure **/blog/%postname%** .

it just says they are updated but doesnt actually update them, my guess is that there is some kind of conflict because I have a page already called blog. has anyone come up against this issue and has anyone been able to resolve it.

so far my only solution is to create a custom permalink using blog1 and then try to use htaccess rewriting to change blog1 into blog but even that is not working, maybe I am doing something wrong but this is my rewrite, which does rewrite albeit to a 404 page

```
RewriteRule ^blog1/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: what is blog1 in your condition?

Comment: It is nothing, basically it wont let me use blog in the custom permalink and I think it is because there is a page called blog, but it allows me to use blog1 or any other word